# CheerioCrawler: How do I ensure a page is fully loaded before extracting the data?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, puppeteer, apify

I have spend the last two days perfecting a list of urls from a site that I want to crawl. My script (which is basically identical to the example for [CheerioCrawler](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/examples/cheeriocrawler) except for the data extraction) is working, but there is a problem. Some of the documents that are saved locally in the data store are incomplete. From the example script, this would be, for instance, that the title field is blank in some of the saved data. In others it's all saved. The only field to get saved every time is `url: request.url`.

My best guess is that the domain I'm crawling is very slow, with multiple scripts loaded from other domains, and Cheerio is just blasting through and not waiting for the whole page to be fully loaded before it extracts whatever data it can find, and moving on.

The total number of pages to crawl is about 2500, so I don't mind if the process is slow, but I'd like to make sure it's complete.

How can I ensure the page is fully loaded before it's extracted? I thought that the `async` function would do that automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential problem is that the webpage loads some content using asynchronous XHR calls made with JavaScript. With the CheerioScraper you will get data from the first request on that site. If you want to load asynchronous content, you need to use the browser to open the page.

You can do it merely with using [PuppeteerCrawler](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/examples/puppeteercrawler). It has quite a similar interface as CheerioCrawler. It opens webpage for each request. You can use there various [waitFor functions](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.18.1&show=api-pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) from puppeteer page interface to wait for the content you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

`CheerioCrawler` uses the [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) library, which is a simple HTML parser. It cannot execute JavaScript, download additional assets or make AJAX requests to fetch additional data.

If you're seeing incomplete results, it means that the page you're trying to scrape loads data dynamically and therefore the data are not available in the initial HTML that Cheerio parses. Sadly, this is a limitation of the technology. To render pages and wait for them to load, you can use a browser that will do the heavy lifting for you. See [`PuppeteerCrawler`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteercrawler).